# Bouncing DvD logo Path

Tags: geometry

I was messing around with animated wallpapers and I ended up finding one for the bouncing DvD logo.
[image: For reference]

So I tried to model the bouncing of the logo using linear equations and made some code to generate paths from a specific starting linear equation. For example a simple one I made would be this. Where the red line is the initial path.
[image: Graph with border 4,4]

After making several more I noticed that if the gradient is a rational number then it always loops on itself however once I set the gradient to an irrational such as square root two the logo would keep on reflecting infinitely and never loop back on itself.
[image: Graph with border 4,4]

My main questions are:

- What determines if the path hits a corner
- How to prove that if the gradient is rational it always loops on itself
- How to prove that if the gradient is irrational it never loops back

Comment: There's a lot of information on mathematical billiards in squares/rectangles. You might find the first few sections of this survey helpful: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.02571.pdf

Comment: Have you heard the term ["commensurability"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commensurability_(mathematics))?